# is Perforce p4v resolve broken?

Tags: version-control, perforce

The resolve function in p4v seems to be either broken or extremely poorly implemented. Lets say when I want to keep the target file

1. When you click resolve it downloads the server version of file
2. If you press keep target it downloads server version of file again

what is the point of downloading the server version of file two times without user permission unless and until the user voluntarily chooses to keep server version over local?

This is very pathetic implementation on conflict resolution. Is there a way around this wastage of bandwidth and time?

Comment: Its still pathetic

Comment: Perhaps you could describe how you think it should work, and why that would be better? There are other merge tools you can use for resolving; if you have an alternate tool that you prefer, perhaps you should set your P4MERGE variable to use that tool instead?